# How to prove the correctness of this algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have my implementation which calculate the sum of list and each of their product. 
For example, if a = [1,2,3], then using my algorithm it would be equal to 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 x 2 + 2 x 3 = 14.
$a_1 + a_2 +....+a_n + a_1 * a_2 +...+a_(n-1) * a_n$
But I'm having trouble of proving this algorithm is correct. I think induction is one way to do it.

Comment: Proving an algorithm correct is typically a sort-of induction. You prove that certain relations among variables hold after a step of the algorithm provided other relations held before the step, etc. -- What *is* your algorithm?

Comment: So in the product part, you *don't* want to include anything other than products of *adjacent* terms of the sequence? [otherwise there would be lots more products]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "don't want to include anything other than products of adjacent terms of the sequence"

Comment: What exactly would it mean for this algorithm to be "correct"?